# Jquery validation error without plugin help me with this friends

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
$('#submit').click(function() {
var $email=$('#email');
valid = true;
errorMessage = "";

    if (valid && $('#name').val() == '') {
        errorMessage="please enter your name \n";
        valid = false;
        e.preventDefault();


    }

    if (valid && $('#pwd').val() == '') {
       errorMessage+="please enter your password \n";
        valid =false;
         e.preventDefault();


    }    


    if (valid && $('#mobile').val() == '') {
       errorMessage+="please enter your mobile number \n";
         valid = false;
         e.preventDefault();


    }

    if (valid && $('#presentaddress').val() == '') {
        errorMessage+="please enter your residential address \n";
         valid = false;
         e.preventDefault();


    } 

    if (valid && $('#drivinglicense').val() == '') {
        errorMessage+="please enter your driving license number \n";
         valid = false;
         e.preventDefault();

     } 


    if (valid && $email.val() == '') {
       errorMessage+="please enter your email \n";
        valid = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    } 

    if(valid && $email.val() !== ""){
            if(!pattern.test($email.val())){
                errorMessage="Please enter email in correct format \n";                
                valid = false;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
       alert(errorMessage);
        }
});
});
```

Id has been verified correctly and also my js is getting called properly error is in this jquery file could someone let me know where i going wrong in this jquery looping validation should i return valid some where some one guide me to know better

Comment: Is your "valid" defined properly with "var" somewhere outside of your snippet?. Define `var valid = true;`. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I must advise you whenever condition becomes false and you want to stop the jquery execution do `return false` whenever needed, this is the right way to handle if else conditions on validations.

Comment: i have given valid=false instead of return false and instead of alert i am using errorMessage to make it more simple

Comment: Can you explain neatly what you are facing as a problem? i Still cannot understand what you are asking for

Comment: its not popping up the alert message and directly code is getting accepted with empty details in my database and email also is not getting properly validated.